# Smooth sample space

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study, bayesian

What does it mean that a sample space is smooth and thus we can represent the target distribution with a probability density function?

Source: https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02434 in section "1. COMPUTING EXPECTATIONS BY EXPLORING PROBABILITY DISTRIBUTIONS".

Comment: Can you share your source please?